TypeError: '_UserObject' object is not callable
I am posting a question because there was a problem in the process of creating and importing custom models from tensorflow.
This is the code that has a problem:
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'    # Suppress TensorFlow logging (1)
import time
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils
from PIL import Image

# PROVIDE PATH TO IMAGE
IMAGE_PATHS = 'C:/Users/###/###/models/my_model/train/20241015_171007.jpg'

# PROVIDE PATH TO MODEL DIRECTORY
PATH_TO_MODEL_DIR = 'C:/Users/###/###/models/my_model'

# PROVIDE PATH TO LABEL MAP
PATH_TO_LABELS = 'C:/Users/###/###/tfrecord/label_map.pbtxt'

# PROVIDE THE MINIMUM CONFIDENCE THRESHOLD
MIN_CONF_THRESH = float(0.60)

# LOAD SAVED MODEL
PATH_TO_SAVED_MODEL = PATH_TO_MODEL_DIR + "/saved_model"

print('Loading model...', end='')
start_time = time.time()

# LOAD SAVED MODEL AND BUILD DETECTION FUNCTION
detect_fn = tf.saved_model.load(PATH_TO_SAVED_MODEL)

end_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print('Done! Took {} seconds'.format(elapsed_time))

# LOAD LABEL MAP DATA FOR PLOTTING
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS, use_display_name=True)

def load_image_into_numpy_array(path):
    return np.array(Image.open(path))

print('Running inference for {}... '.format(IMAGE_PATHS), end='')

# Read and preprocess the image
image = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATHS)
image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_rgb, axis=0)

# Prepare input tensor
input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_expanded)

# Perform detection
detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)

# Process the output
num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy() for key, value in detections.items()}
detections['num_detections'] = num_detections
detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

# Visualize the results
image_with_detections = image.copy()
viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_with_detections,
      detections['detection_boxes'],
      detections['detection_classes'],
      detections['detection_scores'],
      category_index,
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      max_boxes_to_draw=200,
      min_score_thresh=MIN_CONF_THRESH,
      agnostic_mode=False)

print('Done')

# Display the output image using OpenCV
cv2.imshow('Object Detection', image_with_detections)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


This is the content of the error:
(env7) C:\Users\###\###>python detect_camera.py
Loading model...Done! Took 0.019278526306152344 seconds
Running inference for C:/Users/###/###/models/my_model/train/20241015_171007.jpg... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detect_camera.py", line 53, in <module>
    detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
TypeError: '_UserObject' object is not callable

The version I'm using now is this:
tensorflow            2.11
object detection api  0.1
opencv-pythom         4.10.0.84
python                3.7.9

P.S. I'm trying locally on Windows os without using Correp.

tf.saved_model.load(PATH_TO_SAVED_MODEL) returns a model, not a function. You can't call it with detect_fn(input_tensor)
